# Using Flag emojis on VS code

Tags: typescript, discord

i keep trying to use flag emojis for reactions on a discord bot and they just aren't working.

this is the error i get when i try to use something like this > ':flag_jp:'

Is > DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji

EDIT

as requested i have pasted in the exact code i used and the output on the terminal

```
 newMessage.react(':flag_jp:')
```

terminal output

```
C:\Users\zaffar\.vscode\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349
  throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
        ^
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\zaffar\.vscode\Discord 
Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\zaffar\.vscode\Discord 
Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
at async MessageManager.react (C:\Users\zaffar\.vscode\Discord 
Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:198:5)
at async Message.react (C:\Users\zaffar\.vscode\Discord 
Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:767:5) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/channels/924689002571898892/messages/927080749524451408/reactions/jpflag/@me',
  code: 10014,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
```

}

Comment: Can you paste in the code that is causing error and the log that you are getting for us to get a better view of your problem

Comment: @GaneshTiwari i have done so in my edit. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy/paste random emojis directly into your code that will not work if those emojis are not in your guild. You can read more about how to [create emojis](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/emoji), or you can as you probably know create them manually in the client.

Comment: Thanks for the help i posted the code to give a better idea